# Sprout forms internal server error after migration

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

We migrated our dev-Website to the new server for launching the project. Everything works fine except Sprout Forms. We can't access the Plugins settings page in the control panel.

Error says `internal server error, the template „sproutforms/settings/general“ can't be found.`

After we call `craft.sproutForms.someFunction()` in the template our front-end stops rendering. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're missing some necessary Sprout Forms files.  Maybe they weren't FTP/copied over to the new server properly or if you're deploying from Git, maybe there was a gitignore rule that they got caught up in.

If you enable devMode, you'll probably get an error message on the front-end.

Regardless, I'd grab a fresh copy of the plugin and replace the existing `craft/plugins/sproutforms` folder with the new one.